# Configurate nested Router in Akka

Tags: scala, routes, config, akka

I have some nested Router, which shall be created `FromConfig()`. What I want is something like this:

```
test {
  akka.actor.deployment {
    /worker {
      router = round-robin
      nr-of-instances = 5
      /slave {
        router = broadcast
        nr-of-instances = 4
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if I run this, I get an exception, telling me, that `[akka://test/user/worker/slave]` needs external configuration and suggests application.conf.

The names are correct and without the nested routing it worked. What am I missing?

**Edit**

I tried another way to configurate:

```
test{
  akka.actor.deployment {
    /worker {
      router = round-robin
      nr-of-instances = 5
    }
    /worker/slave {
      router = broadcast
      nr-of-instances = 4
    }
  }
}
```

This isn't working neither. I also recognized, that the actual position of the error is not `[akka://test/user/worker/slave]`, but `[akka://test/user/worker/$a/slave]`. That makes it even more weired for me. I understand, that $a is a routee, but how can I configurate it?

**Edit 2**

Thank you for your quick replys. For me this does not work at all because I am using scala 2.9.2 and akka 2.0. Is there a way to achieve something similar in akka 2.0?

Comment: Would someone please add this to the documentation!

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcard in the deployment path name: `/worker/*/slave`

Comment: I am using Akka 2.2.3 with Scala 2.10.3 and this doesn't work.