# Error Configuring Akka Router

Tags: scala, akka

Given the following 2 Actors, `Downloader` and `DownloadActor`, the latter actor has a `router`, named `Router`.

However, when I run `sbt run`, I get the following run-time exception:

> Caused by: akka.ConfigurationException: Configuration missing for
>   router [akka://Downloader/user/DownloadActor/Router] in
>   'akka.actor.deployment' section.

Here's my code:

**Downloader.scala**

```
object DownloadMain {

    val system = ActorSystem("Downloader")

    val actor = system.actorOf(Props[DownloadActor], "DownloadActor")

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        actor ! new URL("http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/index.html")
    }
}
```

**DownloadActor.scala**

```
class DownloadActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

    val router = context.actorOf( Props[Worker].withRouter( FromConfig()), "Router")
    ...
```

**application.conf**

```
akka.actor.deployment {
    /Downloader/DownloadActor/Router {
        router = "round-robin" 
        nr-of-instances = 8
    }
}
```

Please let me know which configuration error that I'm making.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302929/configurate-nested-router-in-akka), but the solution doesn't seem exact (at least to me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `Downloader` is not an actor - this is actor system name which is used to create unique path for the specific actor system, eg.

```
[akka.tcp://Downloader@127.0.0.1:2561/user/DownloadActor/Router]
```

To answer your question, the path in your deployment config is incorrect, you should use following config.

```
akka.actor.deployment {
    /DownloadActor/Router {
        router = "round-robin" 
        nr-of-instances = 8
    }
}
```

All the actors initialized directly from `system`, as in following example

```
val actor = system.actorOf(Props[DownloadActor], "DownloadActor")
```

are created under `user` guardian and are children of this actor. Please read[supervision and monitoring](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html) docs to get more details.